# Running a single Test with Maven command line

Tags: java, maven, automation

I have a project like this:

[image]

I used this maven command to run a test class:

```
mvn -Dtest=WebViewerPortalTests test
```

All the test methods in test class WebViewerPortalTests were executed successfully.

I do the same for test class ModelPageTitle with this command line:

```
mvn -Dtest=ModelPageTitle test
```

but I got error message Nothing to compile and No tests were executed!

I guess this problem comes from the setting of maven-compiler-plugin and maven-surefire-plugin in which I point to /src/test/java

This is my pom file

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>compile mytests</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <testSource>${project.basedir}/src/test</testSource>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.14</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java/</testSourceDirectory>
                        <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/</testClassesDirectory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*WebDriver.java</include>
                            <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

And when I run this command:

```
mvn test
```

only test methods in test class WebViewerPortalTests are executed. I would like to:

1. Run mvn test and all test classes are executed
2. Run mvn -Dtest to execute a test class which is not in the test/java folder

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A few frameworks require the test class to be suffixed with `Test`. Why don't you try renaming your `ModelPageTitle` to `ModelPageTitleTest` and ensure you have runnable tests inside it?

Comment: First it looks you are running integration tests with maven-surefire which is wrong. You should use maven-failsafe-plugin. Furthermore based on the correct usage of maven-failsafe-plugin there naming conventions for unit tests `*/Test*.java`, `*/*TestCase.java` for integration tests `*/*IT.java` or `*/*ITCase.java` which would result in handling all in one without supplemental need for compiler-plugin configuration.

Comment: @mystarrocks: thanks for your tip. I changed the class name to ModelPageTitleTest and it solved my second question. But with first question, when I run mvn test, still only test class in test/java was executed. Any thoughts?

Comment: @khmarbaise: I tried maven-failsafe-plugin, but still the same situation like I described

Comment: Quite possibly that is because of those specific include configuration elements that are on the surefire plugin. It looks like those were put there to workaround the fact that nobody read the surefire plugin documentation to learn about the 'Test' naming convention.

Comment: @LouisTran, it's decided by the [`testSourceDirectory`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testSourceDirectory) of the `Surefire` plugin which defaults to `${project.build.testSourceDirectory}`. That's why it executes only the test cases in `src/test/java`. It's configurable, so you can add your directories to it.